# How to delete rows based on date differences with MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, kohana-3

I need to delete rows where a datetime field is over 2 weeks old.

This is what I have came up with

```
$duration = Date::WEEK * 2; // int(1209600)
$query = 'DELETE FROM properties
            WHERE TIMEDIFF(' . date(DATE_ISO8601) . ', reserved_datetime) > ' . $duration;
```

I don't often write complicated queries (preferring to do stuff in PHP, where I'm more comfortable) but I'd like to know more about them, plus doing this sort of thing in PHP would be very inefficient and I am handling a large amount of rows.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Cheers.

### Update

I gave [Wallyk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353438/help-with-writing-a-mysql-query-involving-date-differences/2353479#2353479) a shot, changing it slightly in phpMyAdmin to SELECT just so I could see what was going on.

This is what I used

```
SELECT *
FROM properties
WHERE date_sub( `reserved_datetime` , INTERVAL 2 week ) >0
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

The only problem however, is that it has returned rows where the `reserved_datetime` is `2010-02-28 10:45:59`, definitely less than 2 weeks ago (from now).

I thought of checking MySQL's internal date. I have been using `date(DATE_ISO8601)` in my queries, because MySQL's `NOW()` wasn't exactly right (it just returned if interested `2010-02-28 20:09:19`).

Is there a way to specify the current date in that query? Any other suggestions?

Many thanks

### Another Update

Here is a screenshot from phpMyAdmin that may demonstrate anything better than my words can. Oh, and the reason it has returned 3 only is because all the others have blank values, i.e. `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

[image: query]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
 FROM PROPERTIES p
WHERE p.reserved_datetime <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 WEEK)
```

Mind that because of using `NOW()`, the two week old date will include the time portion.

Comment: Worked great - is there an easy way to remove rows from the result which have a value of `0000-00-00 00:00:00`? I mean easier than `AND reserved_datetime != '0000-00-00 00:00:00'` ?

Comment: Maybe that only happens when I SELECT. Seems to work fine when I use DELETE. Many thanks for your answer! :)

Answer (score 2):

wallyk's answer is not correct.  Think about what you're doing - subtracting two weeks from almost any date will still be greater than zero (zero = 1/1/1970).  I think you want something more like this:

```
DELETE FROM properties WHERE DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 WEEK) > reserved_datetime
```

Comment: If you don't want it to be to the second (as NOW() will do), you can substitute CURDATE() so the time component won't be there. This answer is dead on though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a mysql database so I can't say if it works for sure, but it does in postgresql:

```
DELETE FROM properties WHERE (NOW() - reserved_datetime < interval '2 weeks')
```

Comment: Couldn't get it to work sorry. Thanks for taking the time to answer though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
$query = 'DELETE FROM properties
         WHERE date_sub(reserved_datetime, interval 2 week) > 0';
```

This assumes that `reserved_datetime` is the field name in the table.

(Tested with MySQL 5.0.46-standard.)